# Fetching tables from a document using Python

Tags: python

I am working on some HTML documents and from these documents I need to fetch tables, which contain certain text in some of the Column headers. I would want to fetch the complete tables in this case.
Can someone please suggest a way through which I can do this using Python?
Thanks!!

I am relatively new to Python. I tried by converting my text into a list format and then comparing the elements with my inputs. But the output becomes kind of nonsensical as it is returning a list rather than a table. So was looking for a suggestion. I am adding the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = input("Enter path of the html file")
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(path)
table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
for i in range(1, len(table)):
    if(table[i].text == "Date" and table[i+1].text == "Name" and table[i+2].text == "Country"):

        a = table[i].get_attribute("class")
        print(a)
        break
table1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(a)
table2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cls_026")
j=1
k=1    
for i in range(1, len(table)):    
    if(table[i]==table1[j]):
        print(table[i].text)
        j=j+2

    elif(table[i]==table2[k]):
        print(table[i].text)
        k=k+2

print("the end")
```

Comment: Look into Beatifulsoup and lxml. These are libraries for parsing HTML

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to read a table from a text file?
Then numpy would be your solution. An easy example:

```
    >>> np.loadtxt('data_table.txt', skiprows=1)
    array([[ 0.2536, 0.1008, 0.3857],
    [ 0.4839, 0.4536, 0.3561],
    [ 0.1292, 0.6875, 0.5929],
    [ 0.1781, 0.3049, 0.8928],
    [ 0.6253, 0.3486, 0.8791]])
```

For more references you can look at this [page](https://penandpants.com/2012/03/09/reading-text-tables-with-python/).